# Ideals in Frobenius Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Frobenius Lie algebra, that is, there exist $f \in \mathfrak{g}^{*}$ such that the bilinear form defined by $b(x,y)=f([x,y])$ is non-degenerate. Since $b$ is non-degenerate there exist a unique $x_p \in \mathfrak{g}$ called the principal element(asociated to $f$) which satisfies
$$
f \circ ad(x_p)=f
$$
and it can be proved that
$$tr(ad(x_p))=\frac{\dim (\mathfrak{g})}{2}$$
which implies that $x_p \notin [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$. Here is my question: Why if $\lbrace x_p,x_1,\ldots, x_{2n+1} \rbrace$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ then $span\lbrace x_1,\ldots, x_{2n+1} \rbrace$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$?.

I read in an article, namely, *Principal derivations and codimension one ideals in contact and Frobenius Lie algebras* that this follows from the last remark(that is, $x_p \notin [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$) but I don't agree with this. I mean, if we consider the $2$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ defined by $[e_1,e_2]=e_1+e_2$, then $e_1 \notin [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ but $span \lbrace e_2 \rbrace$ is not an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$, am I wrong? If so, why?

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample to the claim, which appears right before Theorem 3.1 in the article [1](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2019.1623238), looks correct to me.

What is true, and maybe was what the authors had in mind there , is that any subspace of a Lie algebra $L$ which contains $[L,L]$ is an ideal; but of course $x_p \notin [L,L]$ does not mean that just *any* vector space complement of the space $span\{x_p\}$ contains $[L, L]$, as your example also shows.

Actually, if $\{x_p, x_1, ..., x_{2n+1}\}$ is a vector space basis of $L$ and the span of $\{x_1, ..., x_{2n+1}\}$ is an ideal, it also follows that $[L,L]$ *is* contained in that ideal; in other words, $[L, L] \subseteq span\{x_1, ..., x_{2n+1}\}$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for that span to be an ideal. (And it is easy to come up with counterexamples like yours where that is not the case; indeed, as long as $L$ is not abelian i.e. $[L,L] \neq 0$, we can "shift" any basis for which it is an ideal to a slightly different one where it's not, e.g. replacing an arbitrary basis vector $x_i$ in $[L,L]$ by $x_p+x_i$.)

To fix the issue, one could insert the condition that $span\{x_1, .., x_{2n+1}\}$ contains $[L,L]$; or, explicitly choose a basis $\{x_1, ..., x_r\}$ of $[L,L]$ first, then extend the linearly independent set $\{x_p, x_1, ..., x_r\}$ to a basis $\{x_p, x_1, ..., x_{2n+1}\}$ of $L$.

[1](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2019.1623238) T. Barajas, E. Roque & G. Salgado (2019) Principal derivations and codimension one ideals in contact and Frobenius Lie algebras, Communications in Algebra, 47:12, 5380-5391, [DOI: 10.1080/00927872.2019.1623238](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2019.1623238)

Comment: Okay I got it, thank you very much for the further remarks!